# Error loading SQL CLR XmlSerializer assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlclr

I am developing a solution in Visual Studio 2015 C# where I'm calling a web service on the Internet from SQL Server using a stored procedure
(the SQL Server and Visual studio are installed on different servers).

When I initiate the call from the stored procedure in my SQL Server I get this error message:

"Could not load file or assembly '..(path)..\assemblyname.XmlSerializers.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)

at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)

at StoredProcedures.SqlStoredProcedure1(String land)

I have searched for solutions to the problem and I followed the recommendations I have found:

- In SQL Server, set TRUSTWORTHY ON and enable CLR
- Post build the serializer assembly with sgen.exe in Visual Studio
- Disable CLR Exception settings to prevent exceptions thrown to break the execution.
- Verify the serializer assembly dependencies, place these assemblies in the same catalog as the serializer assembly.
- Try different Permission levels in the database project (SAFE, UNSAFE, EXTERNAL ACCESS)
- Test both using 'Add Service Reference' and 'Add Web Reference' to generate the proxy to the Web Service (gives the same error)
- In the reference.cs file add [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerAssemblyAttribute] with the path to the serializer assembly.
- Load the serializer assembly in the code with 'AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName' and 'Assembly.Load' (adding this to the code gets rid of the   error "Cannot load 
  dynamically generated assembly")

I would really appreciate help with this problem.

Regards
Christer

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you publishing to?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 with .NET Framework 3.5.1

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically load Assemblies in SQL Server / SQLCLR (last bullet point). Assuming you have generated the serializer Assembly, have you loaded it into SQL Server? Is it a reference in your project? If it is a reference, then under its properties "Model Aware" should be set to `True`, which will cause the publish process (i.e. SSDT) to script it and include it in the publish scripts.

Comment: Yes, I have loaded the Serializer Assembly into SQL Server and I have added e reference to it in my project.

Comment: I have now altered the property "Model aware" to True and I also commented out the lines in my code that loads the assembly. With these changes made I published the project to SQL Server and ran the stored procedure and I get these error message: LoadFrom(), LoadFile(), Load(byte[]) and LoadModule() have been disabled by the host. 
StackTrace: at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)